# Prestashop: How to check if product is on a wishlist

Tags: prestashop

Does anyone know how to take advantage of any of the functions of the wishlist module to **have a variable to use in tpl** to know if a product is already added to a wishlist?

If I do not exist, I imagine that some function can be used because when you add a product, if you already have it in the default list, it adds a nity instead of adding it as a new product.

Ideally, for the function you would need, it would be to make a tour not only in the list by default but in all, it is necessary to know if it is already added to a list or not.

The function would be to **show an icon or another according to whether a product is already on a list or not**.

Has someone developed it or could you help me out?

Thanks!

Prestashop 1.6.1.16

---

Thank you very much for the contribution.
I gave the code that I put below and it always gives me a "1" (and if you notice, I invented the product id (which does not exist, since I only have 8 products at the moment).
I made an override of the php of the module:

```
class BlockWishListOverride extends BlockWishList
{


function checkProductIsInWishlist()
    {
        $customer_wishlists = getByIdCustomer($this->context->customer->id);
        $id_product_to_check = 424554224; // Replace by the current product id

        foreach ($customer_wishlists as $cw) {
           $check_product_wl = WishList::getProductByIdCustomer((int)$cw['id_wishlist'], (int)$this->context->customer->id, 
           (int)$this->context->language->id, (int)$id_product_to_check);

            if (count($check_product_wl)) {
                $this->smarty->assign('is_in_wishlist', true);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And in my product.tpl:

```
<p>Is in whislist: {$is_in_wishlist|print_r}</p>
```

Result on Front:

[Result $is_in_wishlist on front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMdi5.png)

Thanks

Comment: show what you have tried - don't just expect someone to do it for you.

Comment: @CFPSupport not only "someone" answered his question, but Bruno Leveque (PrestaShop founder) did!!

Comment: I can not explain what I did not prove, since I did not know what functions to use. Also, I think it's a function that can help the community to refine the wishlist module.
Thanks for the help you are giving Bruno. An honor.

Comment: @DSEO, Please use WishList::getByIdCustomer() instead of getByIdCustomer()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods:

```
public static function getByIdCustomer($id_customer)

public static function getProductByIdCustomer($id_wishlist, $id_customer, $id_lang, $id_product = null, $quantity = false)
```

which are available in /modules/blockwishlist/WishList.php

In your controller file (on the front-end), you could do something like this:

```
$customer_wishlists = WishList::getByIdCustomer($this->context->customer->id);
$id_product_to_check = 42; // Replace by the current product id

foreach ($customer_wishlists as $cw) {
   $check_product_wl = WishList::getProductByIdCustomer((int)$cw['id_wishlist'], (int)$this->context->customer->id, 
   (int)$this->context->language->id, (int)$id_product_to_check);

    if (count($check_product_wl)) {
        $this->smarty->assign('is_in_wishlist', true);
    }
}
```

And then check the `{$is_in_wishlist}` variable in your Smarty product.tpl template.